# How to use the Paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal

I guess I'm not understanding the fundamentals of the PayPal sandbox.
I've created a preconfigured personal buyer account with a balance.
I've logged in, and now I'm going to my site to "purchase" something.

Q: Do I have to point to sandbox.paypal.com in order to test with my sandbox user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do.
You'll also need to create a preconfigured seller account and modify the 'business' of your PayPal , if you use the  buttons.

Sandbox is a bit cumbersome and requires a lot of changes if you use Website Payments Standard (the  buttons), but it's awesome for testing API integrations!

Comment: As for 2013 March, Sandbox is not working anymore for setting IPN of Sandbox accounts.

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Now the SandBox functions work only under IE. I had a lot of discussion with Paypal Tech Support's guys.

Comment: Feel free to send on the ticket number(s) and I'll have a look for you.